# Accessing Props Error in Stateful Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access the parent object within the stateful child component, but I can't seem to understand why the object is not found. This component was converted from stateless and worked fine, so I'm curious what broke post-conversion. Do I need to set an empty array within the state and then a function to setState with the prop?

**Here is the error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: props is not defined
```

At line `this.props.blogs.map((blog, index) => {`

**Here are the two components:**

```
//GET /api/app and set to state
class BlogFeedContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = this.context.data || window.__INITIAL_STATE__ || {blogs: []};
    }

    fetchList() {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test')
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.setState({ blogs: data.blog, user: data.user, csrf: data.csrfToken });
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchList();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h2>Comments List</h2>
                <BlogFeed {...this.state} />
            </div>
        )
    }
};

//Loop through JSON and create Blog and Comment Container Component
class BlogFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            comments: []
        };
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            { 
                this.props.blogs.map((blog, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 blog-card">
                                <BlogCard {...blog} key={blog.blogIdHash} user={props.user} />
                                <Comments {...blog} key={index} blogId={blog.blogIdHash} csrf={props.csrf}/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: How does state look like before you render `BlogFeed`? What is the output if you `console.log(this.state)`?

Comment: If I set that console.log in the render of the `BlogFeed` component before returning the JSX, I see an object with an empty comments array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spotted the error in the wrong line.

The `this` keyword is missing in `user` and `csrf` props:

```
<BlogCard {...blog} key={blog.blogIdHash} user={this.props.user} />
<Comments {...blog} key={index} blogId={blog.blogIdHash} csrf={this.props.csrf} />
```